# GitLab Runner: Failed to register the runner. You may be having network problems

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am attempting to create a kubernetes gitlab runner and I encounter the very generic error `Failed to register the runner. You may be having network problems.` I know `gitlab.com` is reachable from my hosts, but I need more information to debug the root cause of this issue.

Note the error does continue for 30 attempts each the same as the one below:

```
Registration attempt 8 of 30                                                                                                                   
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=107 revision=775dd39d version=13.8.0                               
WARNING: Running in user-mode.                                                                                                                 
WARNING: The user-mode requires you to manually start builds processing:                                                                       
WARNING: $ gitlab-runner run                                                                                                                   
WARNING: Use sudo for system-mode:                                                                                                             
WARNING: $ sudo gitlab-runner...                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                               
ERROR: Registering runner... failed                 runner=dh5qxNxL status=couldn't execute POST against https://gitlab.com/api/v4/runners: Post https://gitlab.com/api/v4/runners: EOF
PANIC: Failed to register the runner. You may be having network problems.
```

Comment: Have you [registered the runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/#linux) already or is this the output from that? You can also do `gitlab-runner --debug ...` to get additional logging

Comment: Nope this was a brand new runner.  The issue was a firewall blocking the traffic to gitlab.com

Answer (score 3):

A firewall was blocking Kubernetes traffic from the host to GitLab.  The runner was created as soon as traffic from `gitlab.com` was whitelisted.